# React.js Dataflow Paradigm - how are data.props, state, and JSX beneficial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React and created a small page that has 4 components (React classes, what is the preferred term?  I'll call them components in this post):

##### Component Breakdown

- a parent "App" component that includes and manages the other components
- a "Form" component that lets the user interact with the page
- a "String View" component that displays the input from the form as text
- a "Visual View" (I know, bad name...) component that interprets the string view and performs actions to adjust the visual.

##### Dataflow

The communication of these components using states and props is as follows:

1. The Form has onChange handlers that pass the new state to the App
2. The App funnels the state data to the String View
3. The String View updates and passes the updated state to the App
4. The App funnels the new state data to the Visual View
5. Finally, the Visual View now updates based on the new state.

##### Sample Code

```
var App = React.createClass({
  handleFormChange: function(formData) {
    this.setState({formData:formData});
  },  
  handleStringChange: function(stringData) {
    this.setState({stringData:stringData});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <FormView onFormChange={this.handleFormChange}/>
        <StringView formData={this.state.formData} onStringChange={this.handleStringChange}/>
        <VisualView stringData={this.state.stringData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var FormView = React.createClass({
  handleFormChange: function(e) {
    this.props.onFormChange(e.target.value);
  }
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="formView">
        <select onChange={this.handleFormChange}>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var StringView = React.createClass({
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.props.onStringChange({newString:'newStringState'});
  },
  render: function() {
    this.props.formData;
    // process formData and update state
    return (
      <div className="stringView">
        {this.props.formData}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var VisualView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var selection = this.props.stringData,
        output = '';
    if (selection === 1) {
      output = 'Hooray, 1!';
    } else {
      output = 'Yes! 2!';
    }
    return (
      <div className="stringView">
        {output}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

##### Questions

1. Is this the correct dataflow paradigm that React is trying to enforce (components only talk to parents, not siblings)?
2. Compared to how I would have written this in just regular JavaScript, this seems terribly constrained.  Am I missing the big picture? Is this dataflow paradigm designed to prevent future problems (if so, which ones? Any that can't be solved with disciplined regular JavaScript?), or is there some other purpose that I'm missing?
3. I'm getting a lot of repeated function names (`handleFormChange` for example, it's used in App and Form View), is there a good way to make these distinguishable? Or, are repeated function names across components desirable?
4. When the components actually build, the JSX stuff gets transpiled down into real JavaScript. Is there an advantage to using JSX?  Would writing components in the already transpiled JavaScript have an advantage?

Answer (score 1):

To start, I think it is ok to call "components", and I've seen lot of people call that way. I will answer your questions below, in an order that I think is better to make my answers make sense.

> When the components actually build, the JSX stuff gets transpiled down into real JavaScript. Is there an advantage to using JSX? Would writing components in the already transpiled JavaScript have an advantage?

JSX kinda mixes JavaScript and HTML, so, it makes your code "friendly". You will create your components, and just "call" them as HTML tags. Below you can see the difference between writing JSX and pure JavaScript.

```js
return <div className="my-component"><p>Awesome</p></div>;
```

```js
return ReactDOM.div({
    className: 'my-component'
}, ReactDOM.p({}, "Awesome"));
```

I don't know you, but I would get tired to write this amount of code just to render a div with a paragraph.

You can check more benefits of using it here:

https://hchen1202.gitbooks.io/learning-react-js/content/benefits_of_jsx.html

> I'm getting a lot of repeat function names (handleFormChange for example, it's used in App and Form View), is there a good way to make these distinguishable? Or, are repeated function names across components desirable?

It is not bad, also, your app is a "demo" one, if it would be a "real" one, it would have some better names for the components (i.e. `<FormView>` would be `<ContactForm>`) and maybe your method names would be different. But it is not bad at all. For example, inside `<ContactForm>` you may call the `submit` handler as `onSubmit`, but outside (the `prop` that you pass), you may call `onContactFormSubmit`, or, in a more semantic way, `onContactFormFilled`.

If your application starts to grow and you have lots of things repeated in the same component (that is the case of your `<App>`), you may try to split your components, therefore, each of your component will "know" about a "domain", and it would not appear to have lots of repeated stuff.

> Is this the correct dataflow paradigm that React is trying to enforce (components only talk to parents, not siblings)?

First of all, React doesn't "enforce" anything, as some people say, React is the "v" in MVC, so, you have your "presentation" layer described as components, and the data may flow in the way you want.
But you got a point when you say "components only talk to parents, not siblings", because that is the way you can "communicate" between your components when you have multiple components. Since a component can't see its sibling, you need someone to orchestrate this communication, and, in this case, this is the parent's job.

There are other ways to make components "talk" to each other (i.e. using `refs`), but having a parent to orchestrate is, IMO, the most reliable (and better testable) one.

> Compared to how I would have written this in just regular JavaScript, this seems terribly constrained. Am I missing the big picture? Is this dataflow paradigm designed to prevent future problems (if so, which ones? Any that can't be solved with disciplined regular JavaScript?), or is there some other purpose that I'm missing?

I decided to answer that as the last one, to sum up some things.

IMO, React is just great, you start to have your "logic" in the right place (a component), and you can just compose things in order to make your page work well (and by well I mean it is orchestrated correctly).

React also makes it easier to "think" about how you will build your interfaces. This Pete Hunt's blog post is amazing, and you should check it out:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

If you would be writing your code with plain JavaScript, you would have to handle DOM in some way (i.e. using a template engine) and your code would end up mixing **DOM manipulation** with your **application logic**. React just abstracts that for you. You can only care about **presenting stuff**. Another advantage is that, when everything is a component, you can reuse those components, it doesn't matter where they are located. If you pass the props correctly, your component will work as expected.

I know it seems exhaustive to write those components, but as you start to write more components you start to see lots of benefits. One of them is to nevermore wonder about how to present your data (no more concatenating HTML strings or calling template functions). Another one is that it is easy to "split" your interfaces, what makes your code easier to maintain (and that is not straightforward when using plain JavaScript).

To be honest, this application you wrote is really simple, and you may not see lots of advantages of using React for building it. I think you should try to create a more "complex" one, and compare it with plain JavaScript. By "complex", I mean "user interface" complex. For example, create a form that allows user to submit multiple "people". And "people" should have "name" and multiple "pet" (which also have a name). You will see how hard is it to handle "add" and "remove" operations in this case, and how easy React handle that kind of thing.

I think that is it, I hope you and React "click". It changed my mind about how to create complex user interfaces.